# MobileFirst - call adapter - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a problem with call MobileFirst adapter from my app. 
If I use swagger docs or postman to test adapter method, it works.
Unfortunately from app preview, I receive message:

> http://localhost:6015/mfp/api/adapters/ServiceAdapter/login?params=%5Btest%2C%20test123%5D net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I don't understand why request to the adapter from my app is forwarded to the port 6015. During the tests (swagger and postman) I used 9080, maybe it is the problem, but I don't know how to change app target port from 6015 to 9080.

adapter xml:

```
<mfp:adapter name="ServiceAdapter"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:mfp="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
         xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

<displayName>ServiceAdapter</displayName>
<description>ServiceAdapter</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>localhost</domain>
        <port>53873</port>
        <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="login" secured="false" />
```

implementation:

```
function login(login, pass) {
    path = 'token';
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : path,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body : {
            contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            content : 'username=' + login + '&password=' + pass + '&grant_type=password'
        }
    };
    return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

and adapter call:

```
function Login() {
    var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
            "/adapters/ServiceAdapter/login",
            WLResourceRequest.GET
    );

    resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "[" + $("#log").val() + ", " + $("#pass").val() + "]");
    resourceRequest.send().then(LoginSuccess, LoginFailure);
}
```

***edited 6.04.2017:***
additionally, i've noticed, that at the moment of adapter calling, i get this error in console from *previewCordova.js* file. it looks like variable *req.url* is undefined:

```
C:\...\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\mdo-app-preview\lib\previewCordova.js:579
    if(!req.url.startsWith('/')) {
                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\..\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\mdo-app-preview\lib\previewCordova.js:579:17)
    at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:491:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_server.js:343:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved a problem. My version of `NodeJS` doesn't support javascript `String.prototype.startsWith` method. So i've added this method to `previewCordova.js` file:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
    position = position || 0;
    return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
  };
}
```

Newer versions of `NodeJS` had implemented `startsWith` method, so `NodeJS` upgrade should resolve problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Mobilefirst App Preview connects to MFP server via proxy which runs on port 6015 and the behavior which you facing is normal, its nothing to do with the port.

`ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` Error is caused due to browser & not from Mobilefirst Server.

Try making request with different browser and also try by clearing browsing data/cache.

Comment: ok, i tried in mozilla and error dissapeared, but adapter call still not working. is it possible, that mentioned proxy not started properly with Mobilefirst App Preview? i've started it with standard command: _mfpdev app preview android,ios,windows --type mbs --noprompt --pid_

Comment: @robr Go through [this tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-to-manage-mobilefirst-artifacts/#preview-a-cordova-application)  to learn how to run apps in preview mode. Also make sure your app's adapter call is working fine in cordova and If it doesn't resolves your problem, Kindly share the error response which you getting while you making calls to server in preview mode.

Comment: I may be grasping at straws here, but it's also possible that this kind of error could be due to firewall rules set up on your local machine - you could have rules in place to prevent anything from connecting to port 6015 on localhost.  This is only a guess, but it is something that might be worth looking into.

Comment: I went through tutorial and checked port rules, but without results. I edited question and described more precisly received error.